# Do your Power Points ever increase past 10?

Tags: magic, savage-worlds, character-advancement

If you have the Arcane Background (Miracles) Edge, how can you get more than 10 Power Points?

There are some powers that take more than 10 PP,  but I can't find out how you'd get that much.  I feel like I'm overlooking something!

Answer (score 7):

Yep, you're overlooking the **Power Points** Edge, which gives you more. It's on page 38 of *Savage Worlds Deluxe*, under “Power Edges” in the “Edges” section of the Character Creation chapter.